# "This advice advises no methods"

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am trying to complete a simple (but, tbh, badly formulated) entry test. I used an aspect to incorporate the request limit feature, but the chances are it doesn't work. The IDE says "This advice advises no methods". I wrote and ran an integration test, and it seems the IDE is correct. **What is my mistake, why doesn't my advice get applied?** I need to aspect all methods within the `org.example` package that have the `@ManageRequestRate` annotation (it applies only to one method, but let's imagine I can include more methods like that in the future)

```java
package org.example.aspects;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.example.requestRateManagers.RequestRateManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RequestRateAspect {
    private final RequestRateManager requestRateManager;

    @Pointcut("within(org.example..*) && @annotation(org.example.annotations.ManageRequestRate)")
    public void annotationManageRequests() {
    }

    @Before("annotationManageRequests()")
    public void requestRateAdvice() {
        System.out.println("Running requestRateAdvice()..."); // a simple log to see whether it works
        requestRateManager.ensureRequestRate();
    }
}
```

```java
package org.example.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ManageRequestRate {
}
```

```java
package org.example.requestRateManagers;

public interface RequestRateManager {
    void ensureRequestRate();
}
```

```java
package org.example.requestRateManagers;

import org.example.exceptions.CrptException;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class RequestRateManagerImpl implements RequestRateManager {
    private final TimeUnit timeUnit;
    private final int requestsPerTimeUnit;
    private final Semaphore semaphore;

    public RequestRateManagerImpl(TimeUnit timeUnit, int requestsPerTimeUnit) {
        this.timeUnit = timeUnit;
        this.requestsPerTimeUnit = requestsPerTimeUnit;
        this.semaphore = new Semaphore(requestsPerTimeUnit, true);
        startScheduledExecutor();
    }

    private void startScheduledExecutor() {
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
                .scheduleAtFixedRate(this::releasePermits, 0, 1, timeUnit);
    }

    @Override
    public void ensureRequestRate() {
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new CrptException(e);
        } finally {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }

    private void releasePermits() {
        int numberOfPermitsToRelease = requestsPerTimeUnit - semaphore.availablePermits();
        semaphore.release(numberOfPermitsToRelease);
    }
}
```

```java
package org.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.example.annotations.ManageRequestRate;
import org.example.exceptions.CrptException;
import org.example.models.Item;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CrptAPI {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @ManageRequestRate
    public String createDocument(Item item, String signature) {
        Map<String, Object> documentMap = getDocumentMap(item, signature);
        String document;
        try {
            document = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(documentMap);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new CrptException(e);
        }
        return document;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getDocumentMap(Item item, String signature) {
        Map<String, Object> documentMap = new HashMap<>();
        documentMap.put(item.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase(), item);
        documentMap.put("signature", signature);
        return documentMap;
    }
}
```

```java
public class CrptAPIIntegrationTest {
    private final ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);

    @Test
    public void testCreateDocument() throws JSONException {
        Item item = new Item(UUID.randomUUID(), "test product name",
                "test brand", "1234-5678", "test agent name");
        UUID id = item.getId();
        CrptAPI crptAPI = context.getBean(CrptAPI.class);
        String documentJson = crptAPI.createDocument(item, "test signature");
        String expectedJson = """
                {
                "item":
                {
                "id":""" + id + "," + """
                "productName":"test product name",
                "brand":"test brand",
                "agentTaxIdNumber":"1234-5678",
                "agentName":"test agent name"
                },
                "signature":"test signature"}
                """;
        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedJson, documentJson, JSONCompareMode.STRICT); // passes, but no log is printed
    }
}
```

[image: IntelliJ IDEA with the message "This advice advices no methods"]

[This questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435691/can-intellij-show-warning-if-advice-advices-no-method) asks a whole nother thing. I have no clue why it was suggested as a potential duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Intellij show warning if advice advices no method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435691/can-intellij-show-warning-if-advice-advices-no-method)

Comment: The first question that comes to my mind when seeing this question is: Why do you not just try and run the application to see for yourself, if IDEA tells you the truth or not?

Comment: Reading the code without having tried to copy and run it, the pointcut looks OK to me. Did you maybe not configure your Spring project correctly for component scan? But really, just run the project, let the aspect advice log something and see if it gets triggered.

Comment: @kriegaex the IDE, alas, was right... Please see the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy, oh boy... Rookie mistake... I forgot to include the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation

```java
package org.example.configurations;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule;
import org.example.requestRateManagers.RequestRateManager;
import org.example.requestRateManagers.RequestRateManagerImpl;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.example")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy // this is important
public class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    public RequestRateManager requestRateManager() {
        return new RequestRateManagerImpl(TimeUnit.MINUTES, 100);
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule());
    }
}
```

However, the IDE is still not convinced

[image]